# c++ encryption, c# decryption = failure

Tags: c#, c++

I have a c++ application (32 bit) that will take an entered string, encrypt it using a code block named WriteProtectedStringValueToRegistry

```
LONG WriteProtectedStringValueToRegistry(LPCTSTR subKey, LPCTSTR valueName, LPCTSTR      value)
{size_t len = strlen( value );

if (!subKey || !valueName)
    return ERROR_INVALID_DATA;

LONG result = 0;
DWORD keyCreationResult = 0;
HKEY newKey;

// Create a new key or open existing key.
result = RegCreateKeyEx(
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
    subKey,
    0,
    NULL,
    0,
    KEY_ALL_ACCESS,
    NULL,
    &newKey,
    &keyCreationResult);
if (ERROR_SUCCESS != result)
{
    return result;
}

if (keyCreationResult == REG_OPENED_EXISTING_KEY)
{
  WriteLog("Opened existing key '%s'\n", subKey);
}
else
{
  WriteLog("Created new key '%s'\n", subKey);
}

DATA_BLOB unencryptedData, encryptedData;
unencryptedData.pbData = (BYTE *)value;

// Save the NULL character in the data
// We need to multiply the length of the string by the
// size of the data contained therein to support multi-
// byte character sets.
unencryptedData.cbData = (len + 1)  * sizeof(*value);
if (!CryptProtectData(
    &unencryptedData,
    L"My Encrypted Data",
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    0,
    &encryptedData))
{
    RegCloseKey(newKey);
    return GetLastError();
}

// OK, so now we can save the data to the registry.
result = RegSetValueEx(
    newKey,
    valueName,
    0,
    REG_BINARY,
    encryptedData.pbData,
    encryptedData.cbData);

// Free the encrypted data buffer
LocalFree(encryptedData.pbData);
RegCloseKey(newKey);

return result;
}
```

Now - in another application (c#, built for any CPU) i am using the DPAPI class from Microsoft to decrypt the binary string read from the registry.

```
private void btnRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    RegistryKey rKey1 = Registry.LocalMachine;
    rKey1 = rKey1.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\XXX\XXX\Credentials", true);

    var value = (byte[])rKey1.GetValue("UserName");
    var valueAsString = BitConverter.ToString(value);

    string decrypted = DPAPI.Decrypt(EncodeTo64(valueAsString));
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    while (ex != null)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
      ex = ex.InnerException;
    }
  }
}
```

Using a test rig, i can confirm the data written to the registry can be encrypted and unencrypted in the c++ program, and using a different test rig, i can confirm the encrypt and decrypt is working in the c# application.

```
    string xx = DPAPI.Encrypt("Administrator");
    string yy = DPAPI.Decrypt(xx);
    // works encrypt and decrypt

    byte[] data;
    data = Convert.FromBase64String(xx);
    rKey2.SetValue("UserNamecsharp", data, RegistryValueKind.Binary);  


    byte[] value = (byte[])rKey1.GetValue("UserName");
    var valueAsString = Convert.ToBase64String(value);

    string decrypted = DPAPI.Decrypt(valueAsString);
```

It appears the starting values in the registry are the same, and running through the debugger, they appear to be very close - up until the four A's

valueAsString
"AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl+sBAAAAesG+C/0ymUSov+q7G6U0rAAAAAAkAAAATQB5ACAARQBuAGMAcgB5AHAAdABlAGQAIABEAGEAdABhAAAAA2YAAKgAAAAQAAAAhMQNYP/ECV0uWNQJNwR0DQAAAAAEgAAAoAAAABAAAAAusIzWvKtWfIE25su1nBkWEAAAACWxuZ2lz12ON/uOafeqdfcUAAAAs7rYAvpeXoSH191clwcFXxmIA9M="  string

xx  "AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl+sBAAAA3lfKy0QLx0KeGBAy9xuuoAAAAAACAAAAAAADZgAAwAAAABAAAAA7y9SEsVpdsVoCO78Vlq+3AAAAAASAAACgAAAAEAAAAG1Ssj5xjVqBhCm2rK9oUtIQAAAA07Fyyoq6vK2OHJ1ygG4t8RQAAACZp6TmW2EBsu7kPVlf05D+jkVC7w=="  string

Here is the registry contents for them...

"UserName"=hex:01,00,00,00,d0,8c,9d,df,01,15,d1,11,8c,7a,00,c0,4f,c2,97,eb,01,\
  00,00,00,7a,c1,be,0b,fd,32,99,44,a8,bf,ea,bb,1b,a5,34,ac,00,00,00,00,24,00,\
  00,00,4d,00,79,00,20,00,45,00,6e,00,63,00,72,00,79,00,70,00,74,00,65,00,64,\
  00,20,00,44,00,61,00,74,00,61,00,00,00,03,66,00,00,a8,00,00,00,10,00,00,00,\
  84,c4,0d,60,ff,c4,09,5d,2e,58,d4,09,37,04,74,0d,00,00,00,00,04,80,00,00,a0,\
  00,00,00,10,00,00,00,2e,b0,8c,d6,bc,ab,56,7c,81,36,e6,cb,b5,9c,19,16,10,00,\
  00,00,25,b1,b9,9d,a5,cf,5d,8e,37,fb,8e,69,f7,aa,75,f7,14,00,00,00,b3,ba,d8,\
  02,fa,5e,5e,84,87,d7,dd,5c,97,07,05,5f,19,88,03,d3

"UserNamecsharp"=hex:01,00,00,00,d0,8c,9d,df,01,15,d1,11,8c,7a,00,c0,4f,c2,97,eb,01,\
  00,00,00,de,57,ca,cb,44,0b,c7,42,9e,18,10,32,f7,1b,ae,a0,00,00,00,00,02,00,\
  00,00,00,00,03,66,00,00,c0,00,00,00,10,00,00,00,3b,cb,d4,84,b1,5a,5d,b1,5a,\
  02,3b,bf,15,96,af,b7,00,00,00,00,04,80,00,00,a0,00,00,00,10,00,00,00,6d,52,\
  b2,3e,71,8d,5a,81,84,29,b6,ac,af,68,52,d2,10,00,00,00,d3,b1,72,ca,8a,ba,bc,\
  ad,8e,1c,9d,72,80,6e,2d,f1,14,00,00,00,99,a7,a4,e6,5b,61,01,b2,ee,e4,3d,59,\
  5f,d3,90,fe,8e,45,42,ef

I must be missing something, using the same cypt32.dll routines, it appears the data should be read and written correctly, but the decryption is failing.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance, it appears that you are using 8-bit char strings ("string") instead of unicode strings (L"blah" or wchar_t*) in your C++ code.  C# uses Unicode for strings.  That may be why you are getting different results.  My first check would be to make sure that I'm passing the C++ strings as unicode.

Good luck, hope this helps.  :)

Comment: Ben -   That is exactly what is/was happening.  Thank you.